# Hockey stick pattern in pascal's triangle

Tags: algorithm

I learnt about pascal's triangle and achieved to print one in Java with O(n2) complexity.
Now for the next part I have to find the sequences of numbers that form a hockey stick pattern and I am stuck here. Any help will be great!
Also [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kg1zzjZS3SM) will help you understand what a hockey stick pattern is in pascal's triangle.
Below is the code I wrote to return the triangle

```
int[][] printPascal(int n)
{
    int[][] arr= new int[n][n];
    for(int line=0;line<n;line++)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<=line;i++)
        {
            if(line==i|| i==0)
            {
                arr[line][i]=1;
            }
            else
            {
                arr[line][i]=arr[line-1][i-1]+arr[line-1][i];
            }
            System.out.print(arr[line][i]+" ");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I tried to do something but I am getting arrayIndexOutOfBound

```
void printSequence(int[][]arr)
{
    int n= arr.length;
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map =new HashMap<>();
    List<Integer> sequence= new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {

        int count=0;
        int res=0;
        for(int line=0;line<n;line++)
        {

            sequence.add(arr[line][i]);
            res=sumList(sequence);

            if(res!=arr[line+1][i+1])
            {
                sequence=new ArrayList<>();
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                List<Integer> resSeq= new ArrayList<>(sequence);
                resSeq.add(arr[line+1][i+1]);
                map.put(++count, resSeq);
                res=0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to find all the sequences that satisfies the rule
nCr+(n+1)Cr+(n+2)Cr+.....+(n+k)Cr=(n+k+1)Cr
And these sequences if marked on a Pascal's triangle will resemble a hockey stick.

Here is how my solution looks like

```
  void hockeyNumbers(int[][] arr) {
    int n = arr.length;
    List<Integer> sequence;
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {


        int res = 0;
        sequence = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int line = i; line < n - 1; line++) {

            sequence.add(arr[line][i]);
            res = sumList(sequence);

            if (res == arr[line + 1][i + 1]) {
                List<Integer> resSeq = new ArrayList<>(sequence);
                resSeq.add(arr[line + 1][i + 1]);
                if (resSeq.size() > 2) {
                    map.put(++count, resSeq);
                }
                res = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you downvote you get a free chance to explain it in the comment section!!

Comment: But where is your function and description of problem you met?

Comment: Specifically, if your problem definition is somewhere in a youtube video, you will continue to attract downvotes.

Comment: does trying line<n-1 resolve the out of bounds issue? Does it create new problems?

Comment: in printSequence, modifying for conditions to for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++) and for(int line=0;line<n-1;line++) avoids the error of looking beyond the bounds of the array. See if it also gives you what you seek.

Comment: but it should not be necessary to test sums. This is an identity. Run down any column starting from the top defined entry and stopping anywhere before the last line. Then go down 1 over 1 and your hockey stick is there. So it should just be a matter of setting the loops over your array correctly and printing each stick.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyKahan for your guidance. I have solved it.

Comment: Great! Maybe post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked the solution and it looks like below. I am storing all the sequences in a hashmap for later use.

```
void hockeyNumbers(int[][] arr) {
int n = arr.length;
List<Integer> sequence;
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int res = 0;
    sequence = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int line = i; line < n - 1; line++) {

        sequence.add(arr[line][i]);
        res = sumList(sequence);

        if (res == arr[line + 1][i + 1]) {
            List<Integer> resSeq = new ArrayList<>(sequence);
            resSeq.add(arr[line + 1][i + 1]);
            if (resSeq.size() > 2) {
                map.put(++count, resSeq);
            }
            res = 0;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried finding the hockey stick through Pascal's triangle with some boundary conditions.(0 < n <= 30000 && 0 < l <= 100) where n is the row number(rows starts with 0) and l is the length of the hockey stick(length starts with 0).But, these extreme conditions create timeout issues.

Now, one way to create [Pascal's triangle is using Binomial coefficients](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pascal-triangle/).

Following the same thing, we can get the hockey stick. For this, we don't need to create the complete triangle. You just need the row number and the length of the hockey stick.
We know that hockey stick always starts with 1 and second index of that row will be the row number itself.
So now, we already have two values of the hockey stick *1 and (Row+1).* 
The next value can be generated through Binomial coefficients using the following :
C(line, i) = C(line, i-1) * (line - i + 1) / i

```
 private static void hockeyStick(int row, int length) {
    System.out.println("Hockey stick statring from " + row);
    List<Integer> finalResult = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, ++row));
    int oldValue = 1;
    int newValue = row;
    int sum = row + 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < length - 1; i++) {
        finalResult.add(newValuebimialCoefficient(oldValue + newValue, i, ++row));
        oldValue += newValue;
        newValue = finalResult.get(i);
        sum += newValue;
    }
    finalResult.add(sum);
    System.out.println(finalResult);
}

private static int newValuebimialCoefficient(int oldValue, int index, int line) {
    return (oldValue * (line - index + 1) / index);

}
```

I think this should be helpful.